# flutter build command is not working getting error

Tags: flutter, build

i run this command in flutter: "flutter pub run build_runner watch" it is happening only in one project and rest all  fine

error :

```
../../flutter-dart/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http_multi_server-2.1.0/lib/src/multi_headers.dart:97:8: Error: The method 'MultiHeaders.add' has fewer named arguments tha
n those of overridden method 'HttpHeaders.add'.
  void add(String name, Object value) {
       ^
org-dartlang-sdk:///sdk/lib/_http/http.dart:694:8: Context: This is the overridden method ('add').
  void add(String name, Object value,
       ^
../../flutter-dart/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http_multi_server-2.1.0/lib/src/multi_headers.dart:129:8: Error: The method 'MultiHeaders.set' has fewer named arguments th
an those of overridden method 'HttpHeaders.set'.
  void set(String name, Object value) {
       ^
org-dartlang-sdk:///sdk/lib/_http/http.dart:703:8: Context: This is the overridden method ('set').
  void set(String name, Object value,
       ^
pub finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I guess you have upgraded flutter to the latest version.You should run the following command and also check `pubspec.yaml` file if `build_runner` is at the latest version, at this very writing time which is `1.8.1`,you can check the latest version [here](https://pub.dev/packages/build_runner#-installing-tab-).

```
flutter pub upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your package's `pubspec.yaml` file, if you don't want to update all your packages to solve this problem:

```yaml
dependencies:
  http_multi_server: ^2.2.0
```

This upgrades just `http_multi_server`.

Answer (score 0):

You should run flutter pub upgrade...it needs to upgrade you pub files

Answer (score 0):

Run the command:

```
flutter pub upgrade
```

It will resolve the dependencies. To see outdated dependencies with more information try:

```
flutter pub outdated
```